# Evaluate spatial variation of density-like scalar

Tags: integration, statistics, random-variables

Apologies if this has been asked previously, but I'm not totally sure of the best way to pose the question.

**Background**

I'm evaluating the variation of a spatially varying scalar field $p$ (specifically, the density of power) across a domain.

As a first step, I simply integrated this field over several relevant subdomains, and divided by their volume to get the average density in those subdomains. For example, for a subdomain I'll call A:
$$
p_A = \frac{\int_A p dV}{\int_A dV}
$$
I then compared the differences of the average density between regions.

**Question**

As a better way of considering the overall 'spread' of the density values, not sensitive to my choice of regions, I would like to evaluate the variance of the power density $p$. Presently, I am evaluating this as:
$$
\text{Var}(p) = \text{E}(p^2) - (\text{E}(p))^2 
              = \frac{\int_\Omega p^2 dV}{\int_\Omega dV} - \left( \frac{\int_\Omega p dV}{\int_\Omega dV} \right)^2
$$
where $\Omega$ represents the whole domain in question.

I would like to know:

1. Is this a correct representation of the variance of this scalar field?
2. How can I relate this calculation with a more 'pure' statistical definition of variance, such as:
   $$
   \text{Var}(X) = \int (x-\mu )^2 f(x) dx
   $$
   I believe I have a conceptual understanding of what the probability density function $f(x)$ represents in this case, but am unsure how it can be written down as an equation. I considered writing it as an integral of $p$ over the domain, including a multiplicative factor such as the Dirac delta function in the integrand to 'knock out' desired values, but am uneasy about the rationale for doing so. Something like:
   $$
   f(x) = \int_\Omega \delta (x - p) dV
   $$

Any input on to this problem would be greatly appreciated!